# How to kill/resolve a reeeeally long-running update in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2005, rollback

A colleague of mine (I *promise* it was a colleague!) has left an update running on our main SQL Server since last Thursday (yes that's right folks, we're pushing 100 hours now!).  The SQL in question (in one transaction, I might add) is:

```
update daily_prices  set min_date = (select min(a.date)
   from daily_prices a       
   where a.key = daily_prices.key and       
   a.iid = daily_prices.iid)
```

(Yeah I know, heinous...)

The total cost in the query plan is coming out as 22186.7, the estimated number of rows to update is around 151 million.

We obviously need to resolve this query one way or another, we realise that if we are to kill the query we're going to generate some brutal rollback, but we've got no way of knowing how far it has gotten.  The only thing we do know is this entry from sys.dm_exec_requests:

```
session_id  status      query_text              cpu_time    total_elapsed_time  reads       writes      logical_reads
52          suspended   update daily_prices...  2328469     408947075           13831137    42458588    151809497
```

So my question is, what would be our best course of action?

1. wait it out
2. kill it and roll back, and hope that it rolls back before the next ice age
3. something else?

Comment: Is `min_date` used in any indexes? I'm wondering if you can do a back of the envelope calculation of how many pages you would expect to need to be written to then compare with the `writes` column above.

Comment: @martin smith - it's not used in any indexes, this was a one-off update that was needed for some investigation work.  How would I go about doing the calc you suggest?  I know it can be done but not sure what that `writes` figure pertains to, is it pages, and if so, is it just the min_date column's pages/bytes that would be listed or is it the whole row?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM sysindexes WHERE NAME = 'clustered index name'` shows the no. of data pages used in the clustered index. On a simple test this end updating a whole table I found writes to be between 1 and 2 times that (I think the 1st one had a lot of page splits). I guess if it has to use a worktable in tempdb  writes could be much more though. Also you haven't said this is causing blocking problems. Are you using snapshot isolation? If so I think this will add writes. Probably best to do a scaled down test on a dev server with same configuration against say 500k rows and extrapolate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So we got fed up with waiting for our transaction to complete, (after a full week on 
one piece of SQL, who wouldn't?), and as it was interfering with our backup 
process, we thought killing it was a necessary evil.

The database started to rollback the transaction.

5 days passed.

We noted with some posts elsewhere on the internet that sometimes some magic 
happened when the database was restarted and the transaction would "go away", 
although these are generally debunked*, and it makes no sense, we thought we 
had nothing left to lose so we gave it a go.  We knew the database would go into 
recovery mode, but the database was becoming increasingly sick anyway and unable 
to run anything but its current rollback work anyway, and we've seen SQL Server misbehave with hogging system resources and not diverting them to where it needs to do the work.

(* we also know enough database theory to know that the DB wouldn't just "forget" 
about a transaction in progress, but we were also seeing stack dumps in the 
SQL Server error logs which kind of told us that the SQL Server was getting 
increasingly grumpy at the amount of rollback it was having to undertake)

So we restarted the database.

Sure enough the database went into recovery mode.  However, the SQL Server event Log 
was now giving us an update every 20 seconds or so as to how long it was going to 
take (in all, it reckoned about 25 hours from the log messages, but it ended up being 
just an hour and a half (!)).

Whether this method of recovery/rollback is faster, I would strongly doubt (as I expect
SQL Server had to do the same level of work to unwind the transaction as before), however it did finish within an hour and a half, either way, I don't want to make a habit of restarting my production database when it is halfway through a rollback).  The update messages in the event log were an absolute godsend, as anyone who has written a batch program 
will tell you; however inaccurate they turned out to be - at least they were a worst case.

As we had the luxury of being the only two people using this production box, choosing to 
send the database into recovery mode worked for us, and gave us informational messages we 
didn't have access to with just our previous rollback state (or at least nothing we could 
interpret given our lacking DBA skills).  Would I recommend doing this in future?
....Absolutely not, however, hopefully the concerned parties have learnt their lesson, and 
we can ask the board for some money for a proper development server! (epic Joel-Test fail!)

Answer (score 2):

I personally would want to wait it out unless I though it had no chance of finishing this week, the roll back at this stage could take far longer than the query has to date. If it's a production server, I really wouldn't take option 2 and kill it unless I absolutely had to.

In terms of regaining some control / working system if you have suitable backups, bring online another database restore the backup / tlog backups, but you will not want to restore to beyond when the transaction was started (or it will still have to roll it back.) This at least gives you a system you could continue dev work against, but unlikely to be the ideal situation for a prod system.

If it's a production server, have some kind words with the individual as to the suitability of testing queries and query plans prior to it being executed. I am sure many DBA's can suggest the less polite methods of instruction :)

Comment: thanks....I think you're confirming what I thought, I think waiting it out is probably my preferred option....the person in question is a little itchy to get this killed and restarted using some more transactional logic, but if we're tied up in an even longer rollback cycle then that will be even more painful as there will be literally nothing we can do once we're in that state!

I'm hoping the developer (who happens to be the CEO, BTW!) in question will exercise a little more caution before he f5's! =:-)

Comment: thanks for your response, we ended up killing it because it was interrupting our backups and production operations etc (see my answer)